# D3 nest formatting date incorrectly

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am getting some odd behavior from the D3.js nest functionality, it seems as if the key and rollup are converting the test_date from a Date object to a string.

Here is my code:

```
var data = [{
    "test_type": "x1",
    "test_date": "2014-07-15"
}, {
    "test_type": "x3",
    "test_date": "2014-07-16"
}, {
    "test_type": "x2",
    "test_date": "2014-07-27"
}, {
    "test_type": "x1",
    "test_date": "2014-07-28"
}];

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;


data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.test_date = parseDate(d.test_date);
});

var result = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {
        return d.test_type;
    })
    .key(function(d) {
        return d.test_date;
    })
    .rollup(function(leaves) {
        return leaves.length;
    })
    .entries(data);
```

And the result is:

```
[{
    "key": "x1",
    "values": [{
        "key": "Tue Jul 15 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)",
        "values": 1
    }, {
        "key": "Mon Jul 28 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)",
        "values": 1
    }]
}, {
    "key": "x3",
    "values": [{
        "key": "Wed Jul 16 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)",
        "values": 1
    }]
}, {
    "key": "x2",
    "values": [{
        "key": "Sun Jul 27 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)",
        "values": 1
    }]
}]
```

I need the nested key value to be a date object not a string. Does anybody have any idea what would cause this?

Here is a jsfiddle with the issue http://jsfiddle.net/2ryahc9L/1/

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't "incorrect" behaviour -- it's how the method is defined, [keys are always treated as strings](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#nest_key) (the same as for a Javascript object or a d3.map hashmap, which are used internally to create the nest).  Normally, I would suggest just accessing the original data value from the first entry in your values array, but the rollup function removes that option.  It's not ideal, but you should be able to coerce the string back to a date without loss of data.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 3):

The function (and object) [`d3.time.format`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting#wiki-format) work in two ways:

- `d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%d').parse('2014-08-29')` will return a `Date` object. It uses the format to know how to interpret the string given as argument.
- `d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%d')(new Date(2014, 7, 29))` will return the string, formatted as `2014-08-29'`.

Besides, the keys in `d3.nest` will  always be coerced to strings. You will need to combine both forms to get the desired behavior. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that did work for me. I had a similar problem. 
I would like to nest data with a time stamp as key. AmeliaBR wrote that keys are strings. But, I would like to use the key as an object, because it should be the x-axis of my chart.

```
var data = [{
    "test_type": "x1",
    "test_date": "2014-07-15"
}, {
    "test_type": "x3",
    "test_date": "2014-07-16"
}, {
    "test_type": "x2",
    "test_date": "2014-07-27"
}, {
    "test_type": "x1",
    "test_date": "2014-07-15"
}];

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;
```

I'm using another field for date only for the key of the nested data without parsing the data as date/time.

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.key_date = d.test_date;
    d.test_date = parseDate(d.test_date);
});

var result = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {
        return d.key_date;
    })
    .rollup(function(leaves) {
        return leaves.length;
    })
    .entries(data);
```

To `result` I'm adding again `test_date` as an object, since `key_date` is a string.

```
result.forEach(function(d) {
    d.test_date = parseDate(d.key);
});
```

I have no clue if this is a good way to do it. 
If not, please advice.
Thanks...

Comment: This is not a very good idea. It simply begs the question, as your keys are also strings. It's even worse, because you are twice iterating over `result` to parse the date. I suggest you dump the first `.forEach` altogether, use the `test_date` strings as they are for your nest and do the parsing afterwards.

Comment: I know that iterating twice over `result` is not a good idea. But I need `data` as it is for further processing. I will take your advice and think about a better solution. Thanks you.

Comment: I found a better solution. I do the rollup in my sql-statement. Seems to be faster anyway.